# Как освобождать std::vector?

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Делаю алгоритм на C++, и в нем мне нужен расширяющийся список чисел. Нашел std::vector, и вроде все хорошо, однако у меня утечки.

Создаю вот так:

```
std::vector<int> openTiles = *new std::vector<int>();
```

Пробовал удалять через:

- `openTiles.clear();`
- `delete & openTiles;`
- `delete[] & openTiles`
- `std::vector<int>().swap(openTiles);`
- `openTiles.get_allocator().deallocate(openTiles._Unchecked_begin(), openTiles.size());`

Помогите, как мне этот std::vector убрать из памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А никак.

```
std::vector<int> openTiles = *new std::vector<int>();
```

Вы создаете `std::vector<int>()`, *копируете его* и благополучно теряете указатель на оригинал. Всё. Утечка неизбежна...

Объясните, чем вам просто

```
std::vector<int> openTiles;
```

не нравится? Абсолютно тот же результат — пустой вектор, и никаких утечек...

Comment: Я не знал что можно писать без new, потому что мой опыт в c# подсказывал что там должно быть new.  И еще - векторы нужно удалять после завершения функции?

Comment: Если он вот так создан, то он будет автоматически удален после выхода за пределы видимости (грубо говоря, за пределы блока `{}`, в котором создан).

Comment: Язык надо учить. Аналогии между C# и C++ до добра не доведут. У этих языков нет ничего общего. Кроме буквы C в названии.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Человек этим и занят...